# linux: flexible buffering command?

Tags: linux, command, buffer

Is there a command available that can buffer an incoming stream for a specified byte count or time period? eg

```
wget -O - http://video.com/myvid.mp4 | mybuffer -t 5s | myvidplayer
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the  `pv` or `bar`  commands with the `--buffer-size` option.

I think the classic `dd` command should allow that too.

Comment: Thanks, dd with iflag=fullblock bs=xxx certainly solves the case where I want to buffer by byte count. Is there anything available for buffering by time?